# How to set width and rearrange of action bar tab programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have this requirement to create a action bar with 3 tabs. I represent them as 'A', 'B', 'C'

[image]

The picture above shows the default state where the first tab takes 60% of the whole width. The second and third, 20% and 20% respectively.

[image]

Now when user tabs the second one, the second tab should be moved to the first tab and maintain the width, 60/20/20. I don't even know where to start. Please help

Comment: don't use an ActionBar and create your own Custom ViewGroup. Probably based on a LinearLayout

Comment: Or use an actionbar and its [ability to display a custom view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int)).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, is there any example I could follow?